# Html.DropDownListFor() Validation works but field does not turn red

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5, form-control

I have seen a number of similar questions and answers regarding DropDownListFor validation, but I have not seen my particular problem.

This is my html helper.

VB:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.AccLev, New SelectList(Model.Items), "Select an Accuracy Level", New With {.class = "form-control"})
```

C#:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(Model => Model.AccLev, new SelectList(Model.Items), "Select an Accuracy Level", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This helper validates just fine if a drop down selection is not made, and displays a validation message, but the field itself does not change to a red border as with the other TextBoxFor() helpers using the same "form-control" class.

This must be a CSS styling issue but I don't know where to look to find the problem.  I have looked at the bootstrap.css and site.css files but there is nothing out of the ordinary that I can see in either of them.

Edit:

The following shows how the Html Helper is nested within a table row within my view:

```
     <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.AccLev)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(Function(Model) Model.AccLev, New SelectList(Model.Items), "Select an Accuracy Level", New With {.class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(Model) model.AccLev)
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(Function(Model) Model.Units)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(Model) Model.Units, New With {.class = "form-control"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(Model) model.Units)
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Naturally the Table is within a form, otherwise I would not be able to use the Html Helpers.  The @Html.DropDownListFor() helper is the one I am having problems with.  As I previously stated, validation works fine for this helper using the form-control class, but the dropdown list field does not turn red as it should, when a selection is not made.  The @Html.TextBoxFor() Helper is using the same form-control class but it validates and changes it's color to red as it should.

It has been suggested that I use the "has-error" class but this is already being implemented within bootstrap.css as the snippet below shows:

```
.has-error .form-control {  border-color: #b94a48;
                            -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
                            box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}
```

The confusion I am having is why is the form-control class working with the TextBoxFor Html helper but not the DropDownListFor helper?

Here is what the output looks like for these two helpers:

[image: one of these things is not like the other]

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your HTML and CSS especially since you think it may be a CSS issue.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 1):

The parent element of your control must have `.has-error` class:

```
<div class="form-group has-error">
  <label class="control-label" for="inputError1">Input with error</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputError1">
</div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation